# Mix was not set up correctly. Please ensure you import or require laravel-mix in your mix config / Laravel Mix v6.0.39

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix-vue3

On a Laravel application, while trying to run:

```
npm run dev
```

I get the following message:

> **npm run dev** 
> dev 
> npm run development 
> development 
> mix 
> Mix was not set up correctly. Please ensure you import or require laravel-mix in your mix config. 
> 99% done plugins BuildOutputPlugin

node version: v14.18.2 
npm version: 8.2.0

No *js* and *css* output to *public/js* and *public/css* is being produced and I get no other error.

I removed and readded node-modules folder several times..

Any ideas how can I solve this issue pls?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution for this error is to insert this line at the top of the `webapck.mix.js` file:

`let mix = require('laravel-mix');`